# How to submit a bug report to Facebook?

Tags: xml, facebook, rss, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

FB doesn't seem to respect ACCEPT headers sent to /feeds/page.php. See below example:

```
GET /feeds/page.php?id=10036618151&format=rss20 HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
**Accept: text/xml,application/xml**
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)
Host: www.facebook.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
**Content-type: application/rss+xml**
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Feb 2012 10:05:49 -0800
P3P: CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: datr=-vIzT4cxw52hjjqTfrpQkNYX; expires=Sat, 08-Feb-2014 16:23:22 GMT;path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
X-FB-Debug: qx/SiyRZDiVPm4wfiKVj37HImPoKM+DVAsO4oKSbSr0=
X-Cnection: close
Date: Thu, 09 Feb 2012 16:23:22 GMT
Content-Length: 41236
```

I cannot seem to find a way to post a new bug report on http://developers.facebook.com/bugs, as I don't have the "Create" (nor the "Subscribe") buttons as described here http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/559/

I have read that there are a fair few FB developers involved with this site, and was hoping that someone could shed some light on what I might be doing wrong / how to request FB changes the code to respect my request, or HTTP406 me.

Comment: your questions is about submitting a bur report to **FaceBook** (http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/) or about your **code**?

Comment: From my reading http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/ is now readonly, in favour of the new http://developers.facebook.com/bugs to which I cannot seem to post a new bug report to. Post is about either posting a bug report, or (if anyone has solved this issue) garnering a good alternative to the issue that is presented by FB not respecting the ACCEPT HTTP header I am sending.

Comment: I've noticed the new bugs site having some issues lately: JavaScript errors that prevent the content from loading or the event handlers binding. Immensely frustrating. Right now though, it seems to be loading okay (for me). I've noticed, however, that even when it's broken for me, it works for someone else in my office.

Comment: @JimmySawczuk - Fantastic, bugs with the bugs site... I have just checked again and still cannot see the Create button. Could I trouble you for a screenshot, so that I know what to keep looking for?

Comment: @user66001 sure, [here's what I see](http://s.jsaw.me/AiE12.png) when clicking "Create".

Comment: @JimmySawczuk Hmmm... This is what I see - http://i.imgur.com/wejMb.png. _Any_ ideas on why I don't seem to have been setup to report bugs?

Comment: Whew, finally... success! James Hill gave the answer to this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044625/cant-submit-bug-report-to-fb?rq=1 Together with Mark Longair's key comments above, that solves the problem and gets the FB bug form to finally submit... Facebook needs a bug report on their bug report.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to http://developers.facebook.com/bugs and click on the Created link you will see a create button on the top right of the page. Or you can just go to: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create

Comment: Thanks. This allowed me to get to the bug create page, but upon spending ~10mins entering in the info and clicking submit, the form disabled all the text boxes and sat there for several minutes (before I gave up). Recreating the info a second time, and then c&p several more times on different browsers / different PC's made no difference. Perhaps the reason why I could not see the page, is also the reason why I cannot great the bug report. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: I was able to create a bug this morning. I was using Chrome on Windows 7. At first I got a 500 error from the server, but now it seems to be working fine. You have to fill out the required fields. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: No luck. Just tried on Chrome Portable 17.0.963.46, and was originally using FF Portable 10.0, both running in Windows 7. In case it is helpful to see what I see - http://i.imgur.com/QJx4r.png. The standard FB 3 bar processing indicator continues to cycle through, but nothing else happens.

Comment: Can you use firebug(FF) or developer tools(Chrome) to see what's actually happening with the requests? I got a 500 the first time, but after that it worked fine. Post your error or return code here.

Comment: This is what I get from the transfer to http://developers.facebook.com/ajax/bugs/create, after clicking "Create" http://pastebin.com/BJ8WH4mb

Comment: It looks like that request went through fine. It had a 200 response. If there were no other pending requests then I don't know what to tell you, except maybe try it in non-portable versions of those browsers (FF & Chrome), maybe even IE. It does seem a little buggy, but it should go through.

Comment: Sorry, where does it specify that the creation of the bug report got a HTTP 200 response? Also, none of my attempts over the last few days have shown up in the bug search.

Comment: In your pastebin link. If you look through it you'll find an HTTP/1.1 200 OK response for the request. I am assuming that you sent me the paste for the request of the form submition.

Comment: Yes, but given the text preceeding and proceeding the "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" it has to be the headers I have in my original question above, and supplied in the bug report.

Comment: Well you should be able to figure out what response you get from the request generated when you hit the create button. It should say right under the name of the file 200 OK or 500

Comment: I just tried to submit a bug as well, and the form behaves exactly as @user66001 described: it's been loading and loading...

Comment: A colleague who has successfully done this (after much frustration), but doesn't have enough rep to comment here, suggested that it might save other people some time if I added that: (a) You need to specify an app and at least one tag on your bug report, even if you problem isn't app specific and  (b) in order for autocomplete to fill in an app, you need to be logged in as a developer of that app

Comment: What web browser are you using?

Comment: @alexy13 - What web browser is who using? I used a later version of FF, but have tried with IE8, Chrome, etc. No difference in result.

Comment: Make sure you have at least 1 app created/listed in the App Dashboard.   Just create a fake app.  It takes less than 60 seconds to go through the CreateApp flow.  Even better: have the admin of the app you are working on add you as a developer (or admin) of their app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the Create button that other people are seeing (tried Chrome, FF & Safari), but if you type something into the "Search Bugs" field [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs), you'll see a "Create a new bug report" link as the last option.  Not the most intuitive...

Comment: Thanks for your post. Could I trouble you for a screenshot, I can't locate any "Create a new bug report" using your directions through my account.

Comment: Thanks, but am starting to get the impression there is something wrong with my account. I see [this](http://i.imgur.com/eXsd5.png) instead. Perhaps someone else should just post the bug and link this thread to it so they could perhaps fix / advise on it.

Comment: Go to Apps tab, you will find a menu item says "Register as a developer"