# Can't submit bug report to FB

Tags: facebook

After browsing FB bugs on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs, and not finding an answer to my question, I posted a question on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042372/facebook-like-button-unsafe-javascript-attempt.

Although I'm still holding out hope that someone in the SO community has an answer, I thought it might be best to create a bug report on FB. Unfortunately, I see no method of creating a bug report. A couple of Google's turned up this tutorial - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/559/, but the "Create" button doesn't show up on my page.

I feel darn silly for posting a question about how to post a bug, but I've exhausted my limited resources.

**Additional Information**

I've tried the solutions mentioned here: [How to submit a bug report to Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234386/how-to-submit-a-bug-report-to-facebook)

Comment: You need to start typing something into the search box on the bug tracker and a 'create new bug' item appears in the dropdown

Comment: @Igy, I tried that, no such option was shown/available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

In the "Search bugs or file a new one..." field, type a title (or just a few random characters, really) for your bug report.

Select the "Create a new bug report" button from the drop-down that appears.

If this doesn't work, try a different browser.

Comment: Tried in FF, IE, & Chrome. Is a special "developer" account required?

Comment: You need to do it from your real account that you use to manage apps

Comment: (but no, there's nothing 'special' about developer accounts, it's just a regular facebook profile that you manage apps on, with the caveat that you need to confirm the account by phone, or credit card before you can access the app management part of the site at https://developers.facebook.com/apps )

Comment: I had to add the "developer" app to submit a bug report. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You also need to have at least 1 app created/listed in the App Dashboard.  Just create a fake one; it takes less than 60 seconds to go through the Create App flow. Alternatively, have the admin of the app you are working on add you as a Developer or Admin for their app, and accept the role as Developer (or Admin).