# Using Facebook Comments Social Plugin -- many Facebook users comments aren't Public

Tags: social-networking, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

I'd like to be able to use site comment features on sites that use the Facebook Comments Social Plugin.  When I'm logged in to Facebook, I see my profile picture next to the comment box and I can see other comments if any have been made.

When I make a comment, it shows up right away, but doesn't seem to register publicly.  If I log out of Facebook, my comment disappears.

More information is coming to light, as well (added March 26, 2013).  There are [several people affected by this bug](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=424116631001496) who have attempted to get help on Facebook with the issue, so far withouth success.

After I added a fake app to my Facebook developer profile, I was able to [post a bug to Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/337187823051879), however it has been since closed without being resolved.

Since Facebook comments are now being used as the exclusive online interaction method by several news media outlets, this problem means that some Facebook users are disempowered from being part of the community discussion of news of the day.  Does Facebook wish for that to be?

Comment: I've browsed the bug list on Facebook and not found a report about this particular issue. I would like to be able to post a report directly to Facebook, but I am unable to add the Developer app (redirect loop when I click the Developer app link in my Facebook profile).  I understand from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044625/cant-submit-bug-report-to-fb?rq=1) (and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234386/how-to-submit-a-bug-report-to-facebook)) that adding the Developer app is required to post a bug report to Facebook.

Comment: [Here is a link to the comments for a news article](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=269276063113750&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D17%23cb%3Df2950037a4%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.rentonreporter.com%252Ff3bdcc8df%26domain%3Dwww.rentonreporter.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&numposts=10&width=626&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tukwilareporter.com%2Fnews%2F181291791.html) which I commented on, for example.

Comment: [Documentation I've read about the Comments plugin](https://www.facebook.com/help/340599879348142) implies that comments made via the Facebook Social Plugin are always public (under the question "Who can see comments I make on other websites via the comment box plugin").  Have I found a bug, or is this a known possible feature?

Comment: An update, long after the fact.  I was able to post my first unmoderated comment using the Facebook Comments Social Plugin on a local news site today.  Either my Facebook account has "matured" enough to no longer warrant automatic moderation, one of my problem reports through various channels has prompted a policy tweak, or my recent attainment of a second Facebook friend has given me enough social media cred to be let out of comment jail.  I'm posting this update in case someone else finds this thread looking for an answer to a similar situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over time and in conversations with many people, I've learned more about this issue.  From [the perspective of websites which host the comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/326412907462211), I've learned that comments from certain users, not on the site banned list, are automatically queued by Facebook for moderation.

Also, I recently ran across [an answer here on Stack Overflow](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7455247/auto-approve-all-comments-in-comments-plugin) that indicates that "Fresh" Facebook accounts are designed to be held for moderation in the Comments Plugin, presumably to prevent someone who has just created a Facebook account from using the new account to post spam comments on other websites.  I wouldn't consider my account "Fresh" but it is still less than a year old.  In the Facebook response which closes the [website report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/326412907462211) they state "The affected user you added to the report has no friends and we suspect the user to be fake and request moderation. This is by design."  While it is understandable that Facebook wants to limit the potential for fake users to post in these comments, this metric apparently also snares legitimate users.

Answer (score 1):

Q.Mark, I strongly recommend that site owners not use the Facebook Social Plugin to support commenting on their sites, unless they want to annoy visitors.

Facebook uses an Orwellian blacklist/censorship model which prevents many people from posting comments. Users get no explanation for why their comments won't post. Rather, it's made to look like a malfunction of the web site, and it is only apparent after the users waste their time composing a comment.

There's discussion of the problem here (among many other places):
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200248881692914

(Copy saved here:
http://burtonsys.com/Why_cant_I_post_comments_on_sites_that_have_the_facebook_social_plugin.pdf )

A FB "Like" button is useful, but site owners should not use Facebook to support comments. Use Disqus, or LiveFyre, or *anything* else besides Facebook.

(I realize this doesn't solve your problem, sorry! But perhaps if enough site owners dump Facebook for comments then Facebook will stop what they're doing.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My question was as a user on a site where the site owner uses the Facebook Social plugin. Not much choice when that is the only option offered on the site, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to post a comment, but it didn't show up on my profile even though share on fb was enabled.

To submit a bug, all you need to do is go to developers.facebook.com/bugs and start typing something in the search field, and you'll see an option to create a bug report from there.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse.  Unfortunately no go on the Facebooks bugs page.  No option to create a bug appears when I start typing in the search field.  I've tried in the three major browsers just in case it might be a browser problem.

I'm not concerned whether or not the comment appears in my profile.  I just want it to be publicly displayed on the site which contains the comments plugin.

Comment: (And just to be clear, the site that contains the plugin does not have moderation turned on for the comments plugin.  Comments posted should be publicly available immediately.)

Comment: You can go straight to the create bug page by this link here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create

Also, you should be able to see my comment on the link you provided, so it seems like the comments plugin works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the bug create form, Jesse.

Comment: When I browse to the comment thread link in my original post, I can see three comments if I'm logged in:  time stamped Thursday at 10:35am (Brian), Thursday at 9:41pm (Mark [mine]), and Friday at 11:09pm (Joe).  However, my comment is not Public for some reason, and that's the issue I'm having.  If I'm not logged in to Facebook I can't see the comment, and I'm not sure if anyone else can see it, logged in to fb or not.

Comment: Update, using the form to create a bug on Facebook, the [Create] button does not save the bug to the system.  Does anyone know what user rights are required to be able to create a bug report on Facebook?

Comment: Yeah I confirm that I can see Brian and Joe's comment but not your's.  It sounds like it might be a bug.  Can you confirm that your Facebook account is registered as a Facebook developer?  Not sure how we expect developers to report a bug about our bug tool if our bug tool is broken..

Comment: I did register as a Facebook developer recently, and I think the response I got was that my registration was successful as a splash screen.  If I wanted to confirm my registration is still active, do you know how I would do that?  It would be more helpful, if there is no badge or other notation in my account, if a permanent notification were sent as confirmation.

Comment: Update: I do see my developer profile listed when I go to the [Developer Settings](https://developers.facebook.com/settings?tab=developer) tab on the Facebook developers site.

Comment: Yeah, that means you are a Facebook developer.  I'm not sure why you aren't able to create a bug, however.  Can you try other browsers and maybe another Facebook account?

Comment: I've tried to report a bug using Chrome, Firefox and IE.  No go in any of them.  I only have one Facebook account, unfortunately.

Comment: See edited post above - I've since been able to post a bug to developers.facebook.com/bugs, but it has been closed without a resolution.  I'm still trying to find out how this is occurring for some Facebook users.  It's a bit difficult to decipher, though, from the outside.